# Can't send both get and post http requests via html-forms on perl

Tags: forms, perl, post, get, http-request

I have switch-structure on my site. 
I work with get requests and I load different scripts, depending on what was in the query. There are switch-instruction in script.
For example.

Link: `site.com/` - printing something like 'press some menu button'

Link: `site.com/?mode=users` - loading script users.pl

Link: `site.com/?mode=address` - loading script addreses.pl

Link: `site.com/?mode=users&action=add` - loading script users.pl and in this script I has another switch which do dif things depending on get-parameter 'action'.

On `_/?mode=users&action=add_` I has form. Action in this form is none (action=''), method=post. So when I press 'send' button this page must be just refreshed with post-parameters yet. Right? Right.

The problem: when I press send button index.pl is loading, not same page. Like there are no get-parameters.

I try to print all parameters, which page receiving

```
@names = $params->param;
print @names;
```

It's printing post-parameters, which I entered in form, but not printing get-parameters from link. Link is same : */?mode=users&action=add*

I tried to print `$ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};` - all parameters shown. Both post and get and their names are correct. 
Whats the problem?  `$ENV{'HTTP_REQUEST'};` is only 'post' when I send form, but 'get' when I just loading page with form.

Perl can't send both get and post requests? What I have to do?
This is how I work with query string:

```
$params=new CGI;
$action=$params->param("mode"); # or $action=$params->param("action");
```

And switch:

```
use feature 'switch';
for ($action) {
    when ('users') {
       do "./pages/users.pl";
    }

    .... some more 'when'

    default { 
       print 'select something'; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know why it hadn't work, but I found next solution. For example link is /?mode=users&action=add (its a form). I just adding 2  to form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='mode' value='users'>
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='add'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with out the slash infront of the question mark
eg change 
    /?mode=users&action=add
to
    ?mode=users&action=add

Comment: You didn't understand me. Action is blank (<form action='' method='post'>)